# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid even when I add table in rails 2.3.18

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

I am  working on maintenance project which has rails version *'2.3.18'* and **rvm use ree-1.8.7-2012.02** [ x86_64 ].
When i am runnin rake db:migrate after bundle install and rake db:create, i am getting the following error as:

```
rake aborted!
Could not find table 'comments'

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

For this I am manually creating comments table as:

```
ruby script/generate migration CreateComments commentable_type:string commentable_id:integer body:text member_id:integer created_at:datettime
```

For this I am getting the error as:

```
/root/Desktop/Projects/community/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:29:in `table_structure': Could not find table 'comments' (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)
    from /root/Desktop/Projects/community/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:28:in `tap'
    from /root/Desktop/Projects/community/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:28:in `table_structure'
    from /root/Desktop/Projects/community/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:228:in `columns'
    from /root/Desktop/Projects/community/lib/extensions/active_record.rb:8:in `columns'
    from /root/Desktop/Projects/community/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb:1318:in `column_names'
    from /root/Desktop/Projects/community/vendor/gems/acts-as-taggable-on-2.0.4/lib/acts_as_taggable_on/acts_as_taggable_on/cache.rb:5:in `included'
    from /root/Desktop/Projects/community/vendor/gems/acts-as-taggable-on-2.0.4/lib/acts_as_taggable_on/acts_as_taggable_on/collection.rb:28:in `any?'
    from /root/Desktop/Projects/community/vendor/gems/acts-as-taggable-on-2.0.4/lib/acts_as_taggable_on/acts_as_taggable_on/cache.rb:5:in `each'
    from /root/Desktop/Projects/community/vendor/gems/acts-as-taggable-on-2.0.4/lib/acts_as_taggable_on/acts_as_taggable_on/cache.rb:5:in `any?'
    from /root/Desktop/Projects/community/vendor/gems/acts-as-taggable-on-2.0.4/lib/acts_as_taggable_on/acts_as_taggable_on/cache.rb:5:in `included'
    from /root/Desktop/Projects/community/vendor/gems/acts-as-taggable-on-2.0.4/lib/acts_as_taggable_on/acts_as_taggable_on.rb:46:in `include'
    from /root/Desktop/Projects/community/vendor/gems/acts-as-taggable-on-2.0.4/lib/acts_as_taggable_on/acts_as_taggable_on.rb:46:in `acts_as_taggable_on'
    from /root/Desktop/Projects/community/vendor/gems/acts-as-taggable-on-2.0.4/lib/acts_as_taggable_on/acts_as_taggable_on.rb:36:in `class_eval'
    from /root/Desktop/Projects/community/vendor/gems/acts-as-taggable-on-2.0.4/lib/acts_as_taggable_on/acts_as_taggable_on.rb:36:in `acts_as_taggable_on'
    from /root/Desktop/Projects/community/vendor/gems/acts-as-taggable-on-2.0.4/lib/acts_as_taggable_on/acts_as_taggable_on.rb:15:in `acts_as_taggable'
    from /root/Desktop/Projects/community/app/models/comment.rb:58
    from /root/Desktop/Projects/community/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:406:in `load_without_new_constant_marking'
    from /root/Desktop/Projects/community/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:406:in `load_file'
    from /root/Desktop/Projects/community/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:547:in `new_constants_in'
    from /root/Desktop/Projects/community/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:405:in `load_file'
    from /root/Desktop/Projects/community/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:285:in `require_or_load'
    from /root/Desktop/Projects/community/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:451:in `load_missing_constant'
    from /root/Desktop/Projects/community/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:106:in `const_missing'
    from /root/Desktop/Projects/community/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:118:in `const_missing'
    from /root/Desktop/Projects/community/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/inflector.rb:364:in `constantize'
    from /root/Desktop/Projects/community/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/inflector.rb:363:in `each'
    from /root/Desktop/Projects/community/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/inflector.rb:363:in `constantize'
    from /root/Desktop/Projects/community/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:162:in `constantize'
    from /root/Desktop/Projects/community/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/observer.rb:157:in `observed_class'
    from /root/Desktop/Projects/community/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/observer.rb:183:in `observed_classes'
    from /root/Desktop/Projects/community/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/observer.rb:166:in `initialize'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2012.02/lib/ruby/1.8/singleton.rb:94:in `new'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2012.02/lib/ruby/1.8/singleton.rb:94:in `instance'
    from /root/Desktop/Projects/community/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/observer.rb:38:in `instantiate_observers'
    from /root/Desktop/Projects/community/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/observer.rb:36:in `each'
    from /root/Desktop/Projects/community/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/observer.rb:36:in `instantiate_observers'
    from /root/Desktop/Projects/community/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:15:in `define_dispatcher_callbacks'
    from /root/Desktop/Projects/community/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:182:in `call'
    from /root/Desktop/Projects/community/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:182:in `evaluate_method'
    from /root/Desktop/Projects/community/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
    from /root/Desktop/Projects/community/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `run'
    from /root/Desktop/Projects/community/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `each'
    from /root/Desktop/Projects/community/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `send'
    from /root/Desktop/Projects/community/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `run'
    from /root/Desktop/Projects/community/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:276:in `run_callbacks'
    from /root/Desktop/Projects/community/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:51:in `send'
    from /root/Desktop/Projects/community/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:51:in `run_prepare_callbacks'
    from /root/Desktop/Projects/community/vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:631:in `prepare_dispatcher'
    from ./script/../config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:185:in `process'
    from ./script/../config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'
    from ./script/../config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
    from /root/Desktop/Projects/community/config/environment.rb:15
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2012.02/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2012.02/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /root/Desktop/Projects/community/vendor/rails/railties/lib/commands/generate.rb:1
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2012.02/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2012.02/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from script/generate:3
```

Please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you show us your model Comment? It might have something to do with it, as you can see in the stack trace:

```
from /root/Desktop/Projects/community/vendor/gems/acts-as-taggable-on-2.0.4/lib/acts_as_taggable_on/acts_as_taggable_on.rb:15:in `acts_as_taggable'
from /root/Desktop/Projects/community/app/models/comment.rb:58
from /root/Desktop/Projects/community/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:406:in `load_without_new_constant_marking'
```

Comment: Thanks sandro, there is some illegal expression in the model. It's working fine :)

Answer (score 0):

created_at:datettime  is misspelled.. it's created_at:datetime

Comment: ok.. run this:  "script/generate migration CreateComments" without the extra fields, did that work?

Comment: I run `ruby script/generate migration CreateComments`, but facing the same issue.